# How to install map/plotting libraries cartopy and basemap using pip

Tags: python-2.7, gis, gdal, matplotlib-basemap, cartopy

I understand some dependencies need to be satisfied before installing cartopy and basemap. I sorted out most of them using `pip` (like `numpy` etc.).

I found out there are some **cartopy** issues with Proj.4 and some **basemap** issues with GEOS.
I thought the python bindings to the Java project Proj.4 were enough and I am a bit lost with the C++ library GEOS (I think GDAL is enough for GEOS, I've linked it to the python world this way: `` pip install --global-option=build_ext --global-option="-I/usr/include/gdal" GDAL==`gdal-config --version ``).

I would prefer avoiding all those things like anaconda, canopy, etc. 
If possible I would like to use only `pip` on both Ubuntu (`apt-get`, only if `pip` is not enough) and Mac OSX (homebrew e.g. `brew install <some_package>`, only if `pip` is not enough).

**cartopy** gets stuck on a version of Proj.4 that is too old. The `pip` output says: `Proj4 version 4.8.0 is installed, but cartopy requires at least version 4.9.0.`.
I was assuming this `pip` install of the python bindings was enough, but it does not solve the problem:

```
$ pip show pyproj
Name: pyproj
Version: 1.9.5.1
Summary: Python interface to PROJ.4 library
Home-page: https://github.com/jswhit/pyproj
Author: Jeff Whitaker
Author-email: jeffrey.s.whitaker@noaa.gov
License: OSI Approved
Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Requires:
```

I don't get why the python bindings to Proj.4 are not enough, even if those bindings are the latest version available using `pip`.

**basemap** is stuck in different ways:

- Using `pip2 install basemap` somehow I get `Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement basemap (from versions: )
  No matching distribution found for basemap`
- But then from the basemap documentation I found that library is not linked to the `pip` repositories for some reason and needs to be installed from the source code. So I've run: `pip2 install https://github.com/matplotlib/basemap/archive/v1.0.7rel.tar.gz` and I believe that a `GEOS` compilation of the C++ code is triggered and after a while it stops with at the bottom this:

  ```
  In file included from src/_geoslib.c:255:0:
  /usr/include/geos_c.h:151:22: note: expected ‘GEOSMessageHandler’ but argument is of type ‘void (*)(char *, char *)’
   extern void GEOS_DLL initGEOS(GEOSMessageHandler notice_function,
                        ^
  x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -shared -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/_geoslib.o -lgeos_c -lgeos -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/_geoslib.so
  /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgeos
  collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
  /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgeos
  collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
  error: Command "x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -shared -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/_geoslib.o -lgeos_c -lgeos -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/_geoslib.so" failed with exit status 1

  ----------------------------------------
  Command "/usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-QVrKRr-build/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-EgAOPT-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-QVrKRr-build/
  ```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong:

- how to provide the correct Proj.4 stuff to cartopy? Actually I would prefer finding an older version of cartopy that is fine with the existing version of Proj.4 (which I am assuming comes from the `pip install` bindings)
- how to get basemap finding GEOS from the GDAL links I've setup with `pip`? If that's not enough, then what should I do more? Perhaps some `apt-get` of a GEOS pakcage that avoids triggering the GEOS compilation inside the basemap installation?

I am a bit confused in this no mans land between Java binaries, C++ binaries and bindings to python packages.

Answer (score 1):

As you noticed `cartopy` requires `Proj.4` lib in version >=4.9. On Ubuntu (newer than 16.04) you can install it through `sudo apt-get install libproj-dev`.

For older Ubuntu, e.g. 14.04, you could simply download newest package from 16.04 ([xenial libproj-dev](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/libproj-dev)) and install it manually. Notice that it depends on [libproj9 in version 4.9](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/libproj9). Remember to remove older version before you update them with 
`sudo apt-get purge libproj-dev libproj9`
Once you done that, open and download packages from links for appropriate architecture (from your log I understand that's amd64). Double click downloaded files in order `librproj9` and `libproj-dev` or use 
`sudo dpkg -i <path_to_file>`.

Comment: This does install proj4 but for me it pulls 4.8.0 not 4.9.0